# SQL get all entries by ids

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables roughly like below:

```
create table user(
    id integer primary key
)

create table post(
    id integer primary key,
    author integer,
    foreign key (author) references user(id)
)

create table user_following(
    id integer primary key,
    follower integer,
    followee integer,
    foreign key (follower) references user(id),
    foreign key (followee) references user(id)
)
```

these tables were created by ORM framework, I want to use raw SQL to get all posts by a user's `followee`, which can be multiple users. Can I do it in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the follower's ID, the below statement will conduct a join and get the follower's followees' posts. You can replace the number 3 with any user id.

```
SELECT * FROM user_following AS a
    JOIN post AS b ON a.followee = b.author
    WHERE a.follower=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select p.*
from post p
join user_following uf on p.author = uf.followee
where uf.follower = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select posts.*
from post posts
inner join [user] u_followee on u_followee.id = posts.author
inner join user_following ufo on ufo.followee = u_followee.id
inner join [user] u_follower on ufo.follower = u_follower.id
where u_follower.id = @USER_ID_WHOSE_FOLLOWEE_POSTS_REQUIRED
```